# Анимация в Angular

Tags: анимация, angular4

Стоит задача по созданию анимации в `Angular 4`. Анимация должна работать как карусель

```
animations: [
trigger('visibilityChanged', [
  state('true' , style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
  state('false', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' })),
  transition('1 => 0', animate('900ms', keyframes([
    style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' }),
    style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })
  ]))),
  transition('0 => 1', animate('900ms', keyframes([
    style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
    style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })
  ])))
])]
```

Она работает правильно,- слайды выезжают справа и едут в левую строну.
Но в слайдере есть стрелка влево и вправо.
Вопрос в следующем: не могу понять, как при нажатии сделать так, чтобы анимация была не справа налево, а слева направо?
И ещё вопрос можно ли сделать так, чтобы пока не завершиться анимация не начиналась другая?